# Background color fill for auto height element

Tags: html, css, height, background-color

I'd like to have the '1' background colour fill the whole box, it seems that the only way to do this is by applying a height to the outer wrap so it has a height value to fill against however I can't give a height to the outer wrap or it will stop the padding from working and display incorrectly.
I have now got this to work by using

```
padding-bottom: 500px;margin-bottom: -500px;
```

I also want to be able to stop my image from scaling down as much as it does,
I've set a min-width/height but doesn't seem to work,  is there a way to do that?

https://jsfiddle.net/xdhpxLqs/

Thanks